# laravel get json data group by

Tags: laravel

I have a table called Gallery and depending on the language column in this table, I want to group by language column Is it possible to do this, if possible can you give an example?

| id | title | language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | "[{"name":"Turkish","slug":"tr"},{"name":"Arabic","slug":"ar"}]" |
| 2 | Banana | "[{"name":"English","slug":"en"},{"name":"Arabic","slug":"ar"}]" |
| 3 | Home | "[{"name":"English","slug":"en"},{"name":"Turkish","slug":"tr"},]" |
| 4 | About | "[{"name":"English","slug":"en"}]" |
| 5 | Phone | "[{"name":"Arabic","slug":"ar"}]" |
| 6 | Tablet | "[{"name":"Turkish","slug":"tr"},{"name":"Arabic","slug":"ar"}]" |

Comment: Is there always a language present within your json?

Comment: yes language required